# How to exclude the header row in html table for table.rows.length function?

Tags: javascript, html

**table.rows.length** in Java script returns the count of rows in the table including rows in `<thead>` tag. What I need is, if there is a header row (inside `<thead>` ) with only `<th>` elements, I want to neglet that row and I need only the count of rows having data in it not the header elements.

Note : I can not use `table.rows.length - 1` as I can not modify Javascript. I can only modifiy in HTML side. Here is the code sample snippet. Here I need count as 4 not 5.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call(){    
    alert(document.getElementById('tab').rows.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="call()">
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>
          header 1
         </th>
         <th>
            header 2
         </th>           
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td> data1</td>
             <td> data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> data2</td>
             <td> data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> data3</td>
             <td> data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> data</td>
             <td> data4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
  </table>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassign `id` to the `<tbody>` element:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody id="tab">
    ...
```

As this element is `<HTMLTableSectionElement>` one, it has `rows` (HTMLCollection) property too, so you won't have to make any changes in your JS at all.